# SIGABRT and not sure how to trace back to calling code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, sigabrt

The error messages and stack trace xcode is giving me don't seem to allow me to trace back to the calling code.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationCenter objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b30530'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2b82052 0x226ed0a 0x2b83ced 0x2ae8f00 0x2ae8ce2 0x59e2b 0x59250 0x13f35 0x13c84 0x2b83ec9 0x10f35c2 0x10f355a 0x1198b76 0x119903f 0x11982fe 0x1118a30 0x1118c56 0x10ff384 0x10f2aa9 0x2614fa9 0x2b561c5 0x2abb022 0x2ab990a 0x2ab8db4 0x2ab8ccb 0x2613879 0x261393e 0x10f0a9b 0x20ad 0x2025 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception`

And all i see is this....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm from the looks of that it seems you are sending the message "objectForKey" to an instance of NSNotificationCenter, which cannot respond to that message. If that is not the issue and the debugger is just being awful try stepping through the portion of code that has the issue to find out what line crashed and post that line, please. But do check the first thing first.

Comment: does not offer objectForKey.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hi thanks guding me through. I finally found the error. The `objectForKey` message was meant for an NSDictionary, but because of some uncommented codes, the message was sent to a NSNotification instead.